# Forget USB stick password

Tags: usb-drive

I accidentally set the option for Ubuntu to always remember the password for a USB stick. I want to be asked for the password each time I use this usb stick instead. How can I make my system "forget" it?

Comment: read [ask] then [edit] your question so that it makes some kind of sense. As it is currently written it is missing some vital clues not least of which is the ubuntu version you are using and how the password was set

Comment: Do you mean a "password" for the login screen? Or do you mean a "passphrase" to decrypt the contents of your stick? Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the app "Passwords and Keys" using the dash and look for the passphrase to that USB drive under the "Login" category and delete it there.